# Consul issue between versions on a cluster (0.6 - 0.7.1)

Tags: docker, consul

I have one setup of 3 nodes of consul cluster , this nodes have a 0.6 version , all run over a docker container inside a private a network, recently in my work we notice the 0.6 version don't support a snapshot commands (and http endpoint returns 404), so I decide upgrade one of that nodes to 0.7.1 in a isolated container, I get running this version in the cluster , but I notice a couple of problems:

1) the snapshot command now fail, I get a 500 error: http: Request GET /v1/snapshot?dc=dc1, error: failed to decode response: read tcp 10.109.140.9:50728->10.109.140.7:8300: read: connection reset by peer from=10.109.140.9:58846

2) I look few endpoints using the UI , and seems they are failing when I browse in the nodes section, I get this JS error " Handlebars error: Could not find property 'tomographyGraph' on object ."

some recomendations over my situation? thanks :)